# Actualizar base de datos en una aplicación Android escrita en Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tengo [mi primera aplicación Android publicada](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geologyapplications.minerals&gl=ES) con su primera versión de la base de datos y he introducido algunas modificaciones en la base de datos.
Intento actualizar la base de datos con el siguiente código en el que he modificado la versión a 2 en el constructor y tratado de copiar la base de datos de nuevo:

## DataBaseHelper.Java

```
package com.geologyapplications.minerals;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DataBaseHelperEs extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private final static String DB_NAME ="mineES1.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    public DataBaseHelperEs(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
         File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
         return dbFile.exists();
    }
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) {
             mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
             try {
                 copyDataBase();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

## DataAdapter.java

```
package com.geologyapplications.minerals;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
class DataAdapterEs {
    private final DataBaseHelperEs mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    public DataAdapterEs(Context context) {
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelperEs(context);
    }
    public DataAdapterEs createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        try {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }
    public DataAdapterEs open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

## MainActivity.java

```
switch (languaje) {
    case "es": {
        DataAdapterEs mDbHelper = new DataAdapterEs(MainActivity.this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        mDbHelper.close();
        break;
    }
```

Sin embargo la aplicación se lanza al instalar la actualización, pero no se actualizan los datos.

No sé si debería borrar la base de datos antigua en el método onUpgrade y qué más podría estar haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando aumentas la versión de la base de datos en el constructor de la clase "Helper", se lama el método `onUpgrade()`, por lo que no es necesario que verificar si la nueva versión es mayor que la anterior:

```
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
             try {
                 copyDataBase();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        // }
    }
```

en cuanto a que no se actualizan los datos, veo que tienes varios detalles a corregir, es importante saber que si estás copiando una base de datos desde assets, a otro directorio, tal vez no la podrás modificar por cuestiones de seguridad en las últimas versiones android.

Primeramente la construcción de la base de datos se realiza en el constructor de la clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper`, no tienes que especificar una ruta específica, ya que se crea dentro del almacenamiento interno en la estructura de archivos que crea la app.

```
 public DataBaseHelperEs(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
        //DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

la creación de las tablas la debes realizar en `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("CREATE TABLE  DATOS (");
        sb.append("NOMBRE TEXT NOT NULL, ");
        sb.append("APELLIDO TEXT NOT NULL, ");
        sb.append("EDAD INTEGER NOT NULL");
        sb.append(");");
        db.execSQL(sb.toString());

    }
```

si al actualizar deseas otra estructura de los campos de la tabla o incluso si deseas nuevos datos, puedes eliminarla en este método `onUpgrade()` y volver a crearla, por ejemplo:

```
public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DATOS"); //*Elimina tabla.
        onCreate(db);//*Crea nuevamente tabla.
    }
```

Comment: Buenas Jorge. Marqué tu respuesta como correcta porque la clase SQliteOpenHelper está diseñada para trabajarse así. No obstante, mi base de datos es una previamente elaborada y guardada en assets, que debe trabajarse con la clase SQLiteAssetHelper. Conseguí corregir los errores y actualizar los datos en mi publicación haciendo el apaño de borrar y recopiar la base de datos cada vez que se abre la app. Estoy corrigiéndo la base de datos con profesores de mineralogía de mi Universidad y trabajando en una actualización de la GUI que incluya por primera vez monetización.